# Ionic CSS animation not working on device

Tags: android, ios, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got a ToDo-List style Ionic app with an `<ion-list>` and `<ion-item ng-repeat>`.

The `<ion-items>` do have the folowing `animation.css` on `.ng-hide`:

```
  -webkit-animation: flipOutX 0.3s;
  animation: flipOutX 0.3s;
```

The animation works fine in the browser but doesn't work on devices (android/ios).
When I debug the app with safari I can see that `.ng-hide` with the right css is properly added - so ngAnimate seems to work alright.

I've tried using standard CSS animation (no animate.css) with all the webkits or ngFX - nothing seems to work - the animation always works in the browser but is never fired on iOS or Android.

To make it even better: It used to work on devices before I updated my setup.

EDIT: Animations do work on devices if I add them to a normal class (not `.ng-hide`) - however `.ng-hide` does get added to the item.

I'm at a loss! What could be the reason?

Thanks for your help!

Here is me setup:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.5 
ios-sim version: 5.0.3 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.10.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in the inoic bundle. See here for details:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/angular-animations-nganimate-not-working-for-ionic-v1-2-4-angular-v1-4-3/41107/6